# Convert date to day name e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed

Tags: php

I have a variable that outputs the date in the following format:

```
201308131830
```

Which is 2013 - Aug - 13 - 18:30

I am using this to retrieve the day name but it is getting the wrong days:

```
$dayname = date('D', strtotime($longdate));
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is what happens when you store your dates and times in a non-standard format. Working with them become problematic.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', '201308131830');
echo $datetime->format('D');
```

[See it in action](https://3v4l.org/WS2nT)

Comment: Updated the demo to use a new fiddle

Comment: Seems like you could use the PHP date function using the lowercase "L" format character to produce the same result. [Click here to see PHP date() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 43):

```
echo date('D', strtotime($date));
echo date('l', strtotime($date));
```

Result

```
Tue
Tuesday
```

Comment: Don't use strtotime(). The date formats for Asia and US can be parsed wrongly. E.g "1/2/2019" can be "1st Feb 2019" in Singapore but "2nd Jan 2019" in USA. Use the Date() object to create date properly.

Answer (score 14):

Your code works for me

```
$date = '15-12-2016';
$nameOfDay = date('D', strtotime($date));
echo $nameOfDay;
```

Use `l` (lowercase L) instead of `D`, if you prefer the full textual representation of the name.

Answer (score 7):

For other language use day of week to recognize day name

For example for Persian use below code

```
$dayName = getDayName(date('w', strtotime('2019-11-14')));

    function getDayName($dayOfWeek) {

        switch ($dayOfWeek){
            case 6:
                return 'شنبه';
            case 0:
                return 'یک شنبه';
            case 1:
                return 'دو شنبه';
            case 2:
                return 'سه شنبه';
            case 3:
                return 'چهار شنبه';
            case 4:
                return 'پنج شنبه';
            case 5:
                return 'جمعه';
            default:
                return '';
        }

    }
```

More info : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

Your code works for me.

```
$input = 201308131830; 
echo date("Y-M-d H:i:s",strtotime($input)) . "\n";
echo date("D", strtotime($input)) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2013-Aug-13 18:30:00
Tue
```

*However* if you pass `201308131830` as a *number* it is 50 to 100x larger than can be represented by a 32-bit integer. [dependent on your system's specific implementation] If your server/PHP version does not support 64-bit integers then the number will overflow and probably end up being output as a negative number and `date()` will default to `Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT`.

Make sure whatever source you are retrieving this data from returns that date as a *string*, and keep it as a string.

Answer (score 4):

Very Simply Short week day name with Month and year

```
echo date('D, d-M-y');
```

output

```
Tue, 16-Feb-21
```

as per my requirements

```
return $item->start_time->format("D, d-M");
```

output

```
Tue, 16-Feb
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you could use date() and the lowercase "L" format character in the following way:

```
$weekday_name = date("l", $timestamp);
```

Works well for me, here is the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `strtotime` as your time format is not within the [supported date and time formats of PHP.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Therefor, you have to create a valid date format first making use of [createFromFormat function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
//creating a valid date format
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $longdate);

//formating the date as we want
$finalDate = $newDate->format('D');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta') );
         $day = $date->format('D');
         $weekendnaame = weekedName();
         $weekid =$weekendnaame[$day];
          $dayname = 0;
        $weekiarray = weekendArray($weekid);
        foreach ($weekiarray as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($value, $request->get('week_id')))
          {
            $dayname = $key+1;
            break;
          }
        }


weeknDate($dayname),

function weeked(){
  $week = array("1"=>"Sunday", "2"=>"Monday", "3"=>"Tuesday", "4"=>"Wednesday", "5"=>"Thursday", "6"=>"Friday", "7"=>"Saturday");
  return $week;
}
function weekendArray($day){
        $favcolor = $day;

switch ($favcolor) {
  case 1:
    $array = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,1);
    break;
  case 2:
    $array = array(3,4,5,6,7,1,2);
    break;
  case 3:
    $array = array(4,5,6,7,1,2,3);
    break;
    case 4:
    $array = array(5,6,7,1,2,3,4);
    break;
    case 5:
    $array = array(6,7,1,2,3,4,5);
    break;
    case 6:
    $array = array(7,1,2,3,4,5,6);
    break;
     case 7:
    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
    break;
  default:
    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
}
return  $array;
}
function weekedName(){
  $week = array("Sun"=>0,"Mun"=>1,"Tue"=>3,"Wed"=>4,"Thu"=>5,"Fri"=>6,"Sat"=>7);
  return $week;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this code block answers the question, it looks like there's a lot of unnecessary stuff in here. Please [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of how this code block answers the question.